# Allow line break with javascript + LivePreview

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a website in two column, on the left, you can write, and it display on the right with a special design.
The thing is, I'd like to allow line break on the right side, but it doesn't display. How could I do that ?

here is a preview of my design. To see the full picture, here is a [> ***Fiddle HERE***](https://jsfiddle.net/z0u6gtbL/3/)

```
function wordsinblocks(self) {
      var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
        initialText = demo.textContent,
        wordTags = initialText.split(" ").map(function(word) {
          return '<span class="word">' + word + '</span>';
        });

      demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join('');
      self.disabled = true;
      fitWords();
      window.addEventListener('resize', fitWords);
    }



    $(function() {
      $('textarea.source').livePreview({
        previewElement: $('p#demo'),
        allowedTags: ['p', 'strong', 'br', 'em', 'strike'],
        interval: 20
      });
    });

    window.onload = wordsinblocks(self);

    function fitWords() {
      var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
        width = demo.offsetWidth,
        sizes = [7.69230769230769, 23.07692307692307, 46.15384615384614, 100],
        calculated = sizes.map(function(size) {
          return width * size / 100
        }),
        node,
        i,
        nodeWidth,
        match,
        index;


      for (i = 0; i < demo.childNodes.length; i++) {
        node = demo.childNodes[i];
        node.classList.remove('size-1', 'size-2', 'size-3', 'size-4');

        nodeWidth = node.clientWidth;
        match = calculated.filter(function(grid) {
          return grid >= nodeWidth;
        })[0];
        index = calculated.indexOf(match);


        node.classList.add('size-' + (index + 1));
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you type an html line break <br> on the left, it shows up in the preview.

Comment: Not on mine. http://www.o-y-o.fr/simon/goo.jpg . But I'd like to avoid html writing :)

Comment: Try it with uppercase <BR> and no spaces between, and it will.  Doesn't help you musch though, except for trying to track down the problem maybe.

Comment: http://www.o-y-o.fr/simon/test2.jpg ok it can break the line, but now one block is going on two line now. I simply search for the word block after a line break to return on the line under

Comment: Here is an image, to make it more understandable :) http://www.o-y-o.fr/simon/testing2.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the source (what you write) by `new line` and then split each line by `space`.

Update **wordsinblocks** as:

```
function wordsinblocks(self) {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
    initialText = demo.innerText,
    wordTags = initialText.split(/\n/g).map(function(line) {
      var spanWord = line.split(/\s/g).filter(Boolean).map(function(word){
          return '<span class="word">' + word + '</span>';
      });

      return "<span class='line-break'>" + spanWord.join("") + "</span>";
    });

    demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join('');

    self.disabled = true;
    fitWords();
    window.addEventListener('resize', fitWords);
}
```

Update **fitWords** as

```
function fitWords() {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
    width = demo.offsetWidth,
    sizes = [7.69230769230769, 23.07692307692307, 46.15384615384614, 100],
    calculated = sizes.map(function(size) {
      return width * size / 100
    }),
    lineNode,
    node,
    i, k,
    nodeWidth,
    match,
    index;

  for (k = 0; k < demo.childNodes.length; k++) {
    lineNode = demo.childNodes[k];
    for(i = 0; i < lineNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
       node = lineNode.childNodes[i];
       node.classList.remove('size-1', 'size-2', 'size-3', 'size-4');

       nodeWidth = node.clientWidth;
       match = calculated.filter(function(grid) {
          return grid >= nodeWidth;
       })[0];
       index = calculated.indexOf(match);

       node.classList.add('size-' + (index + 1));
    }
  }
}
```

Add following `style` in your `css`

```
#demo .line-break:after {
   clear: both;
   display: table;
   content: ""
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7smeqj63/)

Hope, It helps you & let me know if i miss anything.

**UPDATE for Multiple Line-Break**

Update **textarea.reloadPreview** as

```
textarea.reloadPreview = function() {
    var previewString = this.val().replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
    if (previewString.length > 0) {
       previewString = this.htmlUnencode(previewString);
       previewString = previewString.replace(opts.paraRegExp, "<p>$1</p><p>$2</p>");
       previewString = previewString.replace(opts.lineBreakRegExp, "$1<br />$2");
       previewString = previewString.replace(allowedTagsRegExp, "<$1>");

    }

    try {
       // Workaround for a bug in jquery 1.3.2 which is fixed in 1.4
       preview[0].innerHTML = previewString;
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert("Sorry, but inserting a block element within is not allowed here.");
    }

    preview.updatingPreview = false;
    this.bind('keyup', this.handleKeyUp);
    wordsinblocks(self);
}
```

Update **worksinblocks** as

```
function wordsinblocks(self) {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
    initialText = demo.innerText,
    wordTags = initialText.split(/\n/g).map(function(line) {
      var spanWord = line.split(/\s/g).filter(Boolean).map(function(word){
          return '<span class="word">' + word + '</span>';
      });

      var result = spanWord.join("");
      result = result == "" ? "<span class='empty'></span>" : result;

      return "<span class='line-break'>" + result + "</span>";
    });

    demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join('');

    self.disabled = true;
    fitWords();
    window.addEventListener('resize', fitWords);
}
```

Add following `styles` in your css

```
#demo .line-break .empty {
    height: 25px;
    display: block
}

#demo .word {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 2.9vw;
    height: 25px;
    font-family: "helvetica";
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/mksw8qp8/)

Comment: This solution is also almost good, it just miss the double line breaks !

Comment: ok good try ! Still have bugs, see that screenshot of your fiddle : http://www.o-y-o.fr/simon/gof.jpg - seems like a line break can suddenly appear at the end of a "line"

Comment: @Simtwo, Oh, css issue there, you can check again here: https://jsfiddle.net/jvd6vhd5/

Comment: Ok better, now I have trouble with the .line-break height, doesn't seem to change when I change the size is it because it's a span ?

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to control the line spacing... I'd like a doulble line break to have the same heigth as the height of words

Comment: you can set height by adding `display: block` at span. check here: https://jsfiddle.net/mksw8qp8/ (both word & line-break height 25px here)

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Glad to hear that. Well, I update the answer with the multiple  line-break fix.

Answer (score 5):

You can do inserting linebreaks whenever the `Enter` key is pressed. One way is to use `.which` or `.keyCode`:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
     var event = e.which || e.keyCode;
     if (event == 13){
          //do something like this
          return '<span class="word"><br/>' + word + '</span>';
     }
});
```

"13" is the character code for `Enter`. I've tested it in your code and it works fine. You just need to place it (alter it too) where it doesn't affect any of your functioning codes.

Second way is to copy exactly what is in the "Write" panel before doing some actions like separating the words by encapsulating them in different highlights, etc.

---

**[UPDATE #1]**

Just a piece of your code for testing.

```
function wordsinblocks(self) {
      var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
        initialText = demo.textContent,
        wordTags = initialText.split(" ").map(function(word) {
          return '<span class="word">' + word + '</span>';
        });

      $(document).keydown(function(e){
          var event = e.which || e.keyCode;
          if (event == 13){
              demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join(' <br/> ');
          } else{
              demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join('');
          }
      });

      self.disabled = true;
      fitWords();
      window.addEventListener('resize', fitWords);
}
```

---

**[UPDATE #2]**

```
function wordsinblocks(self) {
      var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
        initialText = demo.innerText.replace(/\n\r?/g,"<br/>"),
        wordTags = initialText.split(" ").map(function(word) {
          return '<span class="word">' + word + '</span>';
        });

      demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join('');
      self.disabled = true;
      fitWords();
      window.addEventListener('resize', fitWords);
}
```

Comment: Ok rhavendc sounds perfect, I understand where you bring me, but CAN'T find where to place it... could you give me a hand on fiddle? Here is my last one : https://jsfiddle.net/yagayente/z0u6gtbL/9/

Comment: @Simtwo In my testing, I placed it inside your `function wordsinblocks(self) { ... }` and did a minor alter (trying not to change your codes and logic) and it works fine but the formatting is not working properly (which I guess the `fitWords()` do). I tried again another minor alter and it works fine but the work of `fitWords()` is blinking (See the update above). I guess, the words in the "Write" panel are being displayed repeatedly when a change is being happen (like how `onload()` works). It's up to you if you want to make some changes in the logic so you can get the linebreaks you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Just tried : I guess the "keydown" is also causing trouble, the best would be "keyup" I guess ? but it doesn't solve yet my initial question, because I don't want to loose the design in blocks : http://o-y-o.fr/simon/testing2.jpg <br>so I guess I should change the logic of the code as you say, but I don't see how, do you ?

Comment: @Simtwo I have many ways on how you will change the code but I prefer to stick to what you already have (I assumed you are the one who created the codes so I'll only make few alters). Please look at the another update I made above, it's quite different from my first suggestion. I just made a change for the `initialText` value. Not the perfect answer you're looking for but I'm looking forward to your progress about it.

Comment: I found that code, and altered it a bit, so feel free to alter it ! ;) Thanks for the 2nd update, what you suggest is interesting visually.. but still not it. I guess I keep on searching.

Answer (score 4):

## The short, hacky solution

Change `wordsinblocks` to

```
function wordsinblocks(self) {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
    initialText = demo.textContent.replace(new RegExp("\n", "g"), '<br>'),
    wordTags = initialText.split(" ").map(function(wordWithLineBreaks) {
      return wordWithLineBreaks.split('<br>').map(function(word, index, arr)    {
          return (word === '' ? '' : '<span class="word">' + word + '</span>') + 
        (index < arr.length - 1 ? '<div class="lb">&nbsp;</div>' : '') ;
      }).join('');
    });

  demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join('');
  self.disabled = true;
  fitWords();
  window.addEventListener('resize', fitWords);
}
```

In the `for` loop inside the `fitWords` function, add, after the first line in the loop:

```
if (node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div') continue;
```

Change

```
$(function() {
  $('textarea.source').livePreview({
    previewElement: $('p#demo'),
    allowedTags: ['p', 'strong', 'br', 'em', 'strike'],
    interval: 20
  });
});
```

to

```
$(function() {
  $('textarea.source').livePreview({
    previewElement: $('p#demo'),
    allowedTags: [],
    paraRegExp: new RegExp('something nobody will ever enter'),
    lineBreakRegExp: new RegExp('something nobody will ever enter'),
    interval: 20
  });
});
```

Add to the end of your css:

```
.lb {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssuw6twc/) for complete solution.

## Some thoughts about the solution

Although, this solution works, it is far from optimal.

For example, the usage of the `livePreview` jQuery plugin does not make much sense because it seems that you don't need HTML support as your code is using the `textContent` property after `livePreview` has done it's job which effectively removes all HTML.

This is also the reason why inserting the line breaks (added by hitting the enter key) did not work in your original code. What happened was the following:

- User enters some text with line breaks
- `livePreview` replaces these line breaks with `<br>` due to the usage of the `lineBreakRegExp` option.
- the `textContent` property returns only the text, meaning the `<br>`'s are lost again.

So actually, @Shlomi Hassid has provided a better, alothough incomplete, approach. Incomplete because the sizing of the boxes is missing.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with css instead  `white-space: pre;`

```
p {
  white-space: pre;
 }
```

Comment: Ho, thanks. I tryed it, doesn't seem to solve the problem, see here : https://jsfiddle.net/yagayente/z0u6gtbL/4/

Answer (score 3):

Nice little challenge.
To achieve a nice fit and handle the textarea line breaks:

- Make sure the displayed text has the same formatting as in the textarea: line height, width, letter spacing, size....
- Replace new lines with a `<br />` -> `/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g`
- Use single blocks for spaces -> will make sure double white spaces and white spaces at the beginning of a line will be displayed.

Here is my approach: [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/018d2u21/1/)

```js
$(function(){

  var set = {
     hookTo : ".leftside textarea",
      dispIn : ".rightside .content",
      newline : "@#@"
    };
  //Focus text area:
    $(set.hookTo).focus();
    $(set.hookTo).keyup(function(){
      $text = $(this);
        $tar  = $(set.dispIn);
        raw   = $text.val();
        box   = [];
        //Recplace tags:
        raw.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
           .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
           .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
           .replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
        //Hadle Line breaks:
        raw = raw.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, set.newline);
        //Boxes:
        box = raw.split(' ');
        $.each(box, function(i,e){
         var newlines;
         if (e === "") {
            box[i] = "<div class='wordbox space'>&nbsp;</div>";
          } else {
           newlines = e.split(set.newline);
            if (newlines.length > 0) {
             $.each(newlines,function(index,el) {
                if (el === "") 
                   newlines[index] = "<div class='wordbox space'>&nbsp;</div>";
                  else
                    newlines[index] = "<div class='wordbox'>" + el + "</div>" 
                        + "<div class='wordbox space'>&nbsp;</div>";
              });
              box[i] = newlines.join("<br />");
            } else {
             box[i] = "<div class='wordbox'>" + e + "</div>" 
                 + "<div class='wordbox space'>&nbsp;</div>";
            }
          }
        });
        $tar.html(box.join(""));
    });
});
```

```css
body { background-color:white; height:100%; }
.wrapper { width:100%; font-size:0; box-sizing:border-box; }
.leftside,
.rightside { 
  width:50%; 
  display:inline-block; 
  font-size:16px; 
  vertical-align: top; 
  font-family:arial;
}
.rightside .header,
.leftside .header {
  font-size:16px; 
  padding:10px 20px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.rightside .header { 
  color: black; 
  background-color:orange; 
}
.leftside .header { 
  color: orange; 
  background-color:black; 
}
.rightside .content {
    width:100%; 
    padding:10px 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-size:0;
}
.rightside .content .wordbox {
    outline: 1px solid black;
    line-height:16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.rightside .content .wordbox.space {
    outline: 0;
    opacity:0;
}
.wrapper textarea {
    width:100%; 
   box-sizing:border-box;
    border:0;
   overflow: auto;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    resize: none;
    padding:10px 20px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:arial;
    line-height:16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    min-height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="leftside">
        <div class="header">Write</div>
        <textarea placeholder="Type here please"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="rightside">
        <div class="header">See</div>
        <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the closest because it allow to make double line breaks, but it doesn't load the sizing of the boxes ! Almost there !

Comment: What do you mean by "the sizing of the boxes"?

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/z0u6gtbL/3/ Every word is placed in boxes (span) based on the size of the word (the function "wordsinblocks" which is in the question)